# Not able to create bot registration on azure using REST API

Tags: azure, botframework

I have created App Service, Application Insights and Storage using REST API. But I'm not able to create Web app bot(Bot Registration page) using REST API. If it is possible to create, please help.

Answer (score 0):

After you've [registered your client with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad), you need to [create the Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdate). Be sure to use the following in the body:

- **kind** "webapp"
- **location**  Geographic location used to create the bot service resources. For example, eastus, westus, westus2, and so on.

I'm unable to test this due to Azure subscription limitations.

Alternatively, you can use the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) by running:

```sh
az bot create --kind webapp --name <bot-name-in-azure> --location <geographic-location> --version v4 --lang <language> --verbose --resource-group <resource-group-name> --appid "<application-id>" --password "<application-password>" --verbose
```

The doc I got this from is currently in preview, but here's an explanation of the parameters:

[image]